# Call a Javascript function from dynamically created html form button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, methods, global

I have a javascript file where I am creating a form using html tags. On this form there are 2 buttons: <kbd>Confirm</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd>. When the user clicks on the cancel, the form will be discarded. I have written the method to close the form within the same javascript file that contains the code to create the form elements dynamically. But, I am getting the following error on the console when I try to close the form.

> Error
>   [image: error]

**Javascript button that Calls the method**

```
...
$("#lot").append(
        "<div class='form-group'></br>"+
            "<label class='col-md-12 control-label' for='tableFormConfirmButton'></label></br>"+
            "<label class='col-md-12 control-label' for='tableFormConfirmButton'></label></br>"+
            "<label class='col-md-12 control-label' for='tableFormConfirmButton'></label></br>"+
            "<label class='col-md-2 control-label' for='tableFormConfirmButton'></label>"+
            "&nbsp<button id='tableFormConfirmButton' name='tableFormConfirmButton' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='storeTableFormInfo("+newAgent+","+i+","+e+","+mouseTop+","+mouseLeft+","+elemType+")'>Confirm</button>"+
            "&nbsp&nbsp<button id='tableFormCancelButton' name='tableFormCancelButton' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='closeForm()'>Cancel</button>"+
        "</div></br>"
); 
...
```

**closeForm() method in the same file**

```
function closeForm()
{
    var myNode = document.getElementById("lot");
    var fc = myNode.firstChild;

    while( fc ) {
        myNode.removeChild( fc );
        fc = myNode.firstChild;
    }

    $(".toolbox-titlex").hide();
    $(".panel").hide();

    $("#container").removeClass("disabledbutton");
    $("#toolbox").removeClass("disabledbutton");
}
```

I tried adding the `closeForm()` method in the main JSP page under a `<script>` tag and then it worked. But my issue here is that I've already referenced this javascript file in that JSP as `<script src="resources/js/taro/Customscripts/VisualEditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` under the `<head>`. So why is it not recognizing the method?

Any suggestions in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: are you including the source of jQuery?

Comment: For “old-school” event handling via HTML attributes, the function must exist _before_ the HTML element. But why are you using that here anyway - you are using jQuery, so use its event handling mechanism, and don’t mix it with the old-school one.

Comment: @Nayantra Are you sure there are no errors when you use the js file?

Comment: When calling the onclick - the file where closeForm is defined doesn't matter - it has be globally exposed (hence why this method is discouraged). 

Is the closeForm available on the window object?

Comment: @reporter Yes. I've been using this js file's other methods without any errors. The only issue occurs when I call the method on an `onclick`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to attach the click event inside the ready function using jQuery to be sure that all the code is loaded before attachement of the event :

```
$(function(){
    $('#tableFormCancelButton').on('click', closeForm);
});
```

And remove the inline event `onclick='closeForm()'` from the button.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This appears to be a quirk of jQuery. In normal HTML, script elements creating functions called by in-line listeners can be anywhere, including after the HTML with the listener. An alternative should be to put the declaration of *closeForm* before the code that attaches it as a listener.

Answer (score 0):

Try change `onclick='closeForm()'` to `onclick='test()'` and on JSP add

```
function test (){
   closeForm();
};
```

Hope this helps.